# He appointed me to do the duty. (vs. To do the duty, he appointed me.)

Tags: verbs

> He appointed me to do the duty.

> To do the duty, he appointed me.

> He appointed me, to do the duty.

Is there any difference between them?

My question arises from the structure like cause A to do something or enable A to do something or encourage A to do B: appoint A to do B' is the same usage/structure/grammar of 'cause A to do B?

Comment: I can't easily imagine a context where the comma (reflecting a pause in speech) would be justified in #3, but I wouldn't like to rule out the possibility. The comma is perhaps easier to accept in #2 - but it still wouldn't *normally* be justified, and the unusual inversion would normally be dismissed as "clumsy" anyway. Also, I'm not clear exactly what "do the duty" means. Consider the situation if we replace "duty" by "job". In that case, there's potentially a clear difference between *He appointed me **to the job*** and ***...to do the job.*** But with ***duty**?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree, jod is a better fit than duty. The only justification for a comma in #3 may be for emphasis "He appointed **me**, to do the job. [not you]"

Comment: @PeterJennings: You're *probably* right, since the OP here *probably* isn't aware of the potential subtleties involved. But if we knew the text came from a competent native speaker, we might simply assume that *without **do*** "the duty" refers to *one specific rostered duty shift*. It's a bit more unusual *with **do***, but I could get my head round that as referring to some *regular* chore that needed to be assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first sentence is ambiguous.

The natural interpretation has the meaning, "He hired me so that I would do the duty".

But it could also be parsed to mean, "He hired me in order to do his duty". This could occur in a context where either hiring me is his duty, or in order to be able to do his duty he had to hire me first, but without such a context, few would consider this meaning.

The second sentence only has the second meaning, that he hired me in order to do his duty.

The third sentence isn't natural at all.

Comment: The first sentence is technically ambiguous but I think almost everybody would take your first interpretation.